# PrestaShop 1 Click Upgrade Access Denied

Tags: prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

Please help me in upgrading Prestashop 1.6 to 1.7 as I am new to it . When I tried  to click on "1 Click Upgrade" from admin it says "Access Denied" .

What's the problem with it ?

This is the screenshot : 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

"1 Click Upgrade" only allows you to upgrade lower Prestashop version to 1.6, or from minor Prestashop 1.7 to the latest version of Prestashop 1.7. That's why the error happens. 
But there is a free module that helps you migrate your website from 1.6 to 1.7: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/820013-migrate-or-upgrade-prestashop-16-or-other-versions-to-17-%E2%80%93-free-module/

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete all contents in the new 'var' folder (except the .htaccess).
Deleting cache, sessions and logs solved that issue for me. (Prestashop recreates everything).